# use mysql order by and limit,the same record appears in two page

Tags: mysql, limit

this is my sql:

```
SELECT ID
FROM table R
ORDER BY rank desc limit 0,25;
```

all records`s rank is 0.

I set pase size as 25 by using limit.
So using limit 0,25,I get the first page;
using limit 25,25,I get the second page.

the problem is,one record is appeared in two page both.

I guess this is a bug with mysql.
My mysql`s version is 5.6.24.

can anyone help me?

Comment: *"all records`s rank is 0."* -- there is no unique order of records when you `ORDER BY rank`. Even `LIMIT 0,25` can return different rows on different executions if the table is updated or compacted (or after restoring the data from backup).

Comment: If all records Rank is 0. Then, why Order By?

Comment: But my table has never updated nor compacted.It has no change.
So the result are not guaranteed identical in each execution?

Comment: @mascure it doesn't really matter. The idea is that MySQL returns record sets. A [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)) is, by definition, an unordered collection of items. The SQL language allows sorting the result set but when a tie occurs, the *unordered* property of sets prevails. The database engine aims for speed and it doesn't consume additional resources and time to make sure the "equal" rows are returned always in the same order because there is no requirement to work this way.

Comment: Btw,  [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/198169/duplicate-results-in-mysql-query-when-try-to-sort-by-with-limit-and-offset) is another question  with same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> all records`s rank is 0.

There is no unique order of records when you `ORDER BY rank`. Even `LIMIT 0,25` can return different rows on different executions if the table is updated or compacted (or after restoring the data from backup) and it is not wrong.

Use `ORDER BY rank DESC, ID DESC`, f.e., to be sure that the rows that rank equal are always returned in the same order.

I added `ID DESC` to get the most recent rows first. If the table contains a column that stores the last modified date then use it instead of `ID`. Or create another sorting rule that fits your application better.